# wget and curl always result in corrupted file

Tags: powershell, download, corrupt

I'm trying to download a file using wget, so I do:

```
wget 'url' -o 'path.file-extension'
```

Everytime the download succeeds, but the file gets corrupted. Also tried downloading using curl, but results in the same corrupted file.
How do I fix this?
*(nothing I found on other posts worked so far)*

edit 2: The url I had was suspended and re-opened multiple times, resulted in html download -> -o made it .mp3 -> file got corrupted. Also explains why it sometimes worked.

Comment: Is this a `powershell` issue? a `wget` issue? a `curl` issue?  You know powershell aliases `wget` and `curl` to `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` respectively?  Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: I just enter `wget 'url' -o 'path'` in powershell. No error messages are visible, but the file is corrupted.

Comment: Are you specifying any headers?  What is the extension of the output file?  You aren't actually using `wget` OR `curl`, but the `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` powershell cmdlet aliases.

Comment: It's a mp3, but I also tried using a zip file, same result. (weird thing is it just worked, no corrupted file, but now it doesn't anymore...)

Comment: What happens if you do `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'url'` without the `-o` switch?  Please add the response to your question.

Comment: Will try in about a hour, can’t test rn.

Comment: Respone added to post.

Comment: You're hitting an html page, not a mp3 download.  That's your problem.

Comment: That’s the weird thing. It sometimes just works fine. Mp3 starts playing, everything works. But sometimes it gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url I had was suspended and re-opened multiple times, resulted in html download -> -o made it .mp3 -> file got corrupted. Also explains why it sometimes worked.

edit: can't accept as answer rn...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add --compression=none

```
wget 'url' -o 'path.file-extension'--compression=none
```

Comment: I get the following error: Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'compression=none'.

Answer (score -1):

Using invoke-webrequest (alias wget) to download files from sourceforge produces corrupt files if run in the simple form:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://sourceforge.net/projects/path/to/file -OutFile 'mydownloadedfile.ext'
```

It seems reliable if amended to specify a user agent

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://sourceforge.net/projects/path/to/file -OutFile 'mydownloadedfile.ext' -UserAgent [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::Chrome
```

It also worked for me when specifying Safari as the user agent. This isn't installed on my PC so it seems that the useragent is working as expected by describing a behaviour rather than a piece of software.